# Shell - Insert selected columns from a table to an other one

Tags: mysql, shell

I want to run a query in a database then insert result in an other one.
I want to make a script but I don't have an idea how can I dot it.

Example :

```
Database 1 : Select name , count(*) as NBName from db1.table1
Database 2 : Insert into table2 values ("test1", 10), ("test2",20)
where "test1", 10 ... are the result of the first query.
```

Thank you :)

Comment: If the server is the same and you've got a user with appropriate permissions, you can do it with a single statement. You've got to specify your tables in the form database.table in this case.

Comment: They are in the same server but with different username/password ? Could you give me more details please ?

Comment: Different user/password-combination. Then it won't work. Otherwise you could have used: `INSERT INTO db2.table2 SELECT name, COUNT(*) FROM db1.table1`